# Using UIActivityViewController to make image links on facebook and twitter

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using a cocoa touch UIActivityViewController, and I would like to post an image thumbnail with a link that can be touched or clicked, and that would take them to the link. If possible I would like the link to not appear in the posts's body.

The user should also be able to write a custom message for this post.

For now I only seem to be able to post a link with a picture, but picture is not the link.

Thanks,

Sam.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if that's what u want but try this

```
NSString *someText = @"TEST!";
UIImage *shareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"];
NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.somepage.com"];
self.dataToShare = @[self.someText,shareImage,shareUrl];
 self.activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:self.dataToShare
                                  applicationActivities: nil];
```

Hope it helps! :D